Why didn't Islam bring the best out of the people? i.e why didnt Islam make Muslims successful in all the aspects of life?
I get answers like "Look at Golden Age" but isn't Golden age a cause of Greek Philosophy and not Islam? I dont understand why Islam takes credit for it can someone elaborate? What in the religion of Islam would cause such a development?
Even if it has caused the Golden age, isn't it just a speck of time in a huge 1400 years of timeline where vast majority of time Muslims lived miserably or comparatively worse than Kuffar?
Why would God create a Religion when he knows his system of life would make life miserable ?
In no way I'm tryna throw shade on Islam, as a revert I am hopeless and Im not finding answers anywhere. I dont find the scholars of Islam as much of a thinkers.

I guess the down-voter shares your thoughts and is frightened by them.

@GyroGearloose Atleast they could've reasoned why they disagree, but no.

As far as I know (or think to know) the Golden Age was achieved by peace, tolerance and open-mindedness: peace between the arch-rivals, Arabs and Persians, tolerance against other people of The Book (and for many others, too), and open-mindedness to allow thoughts that were not literally written in the Quran (as long as they did not openly contradict). The opposite of hate, based on ethnics, intolerance to everyone that does things only slightly different, and deliberate narrow-mindedness, out of fear.

@Hardshell , this is a topic my teacher, may Allah have mercy on him, gave me some advice about. The conclusion he drew was that our own idea of successful in life is completely wrong, as we often see those with wealth as successful. With true faith in Allah, the people in the world are the most content, but we do not see them as they are few and are not displayed to the world. This idea of Muslims 'struggling' is both a part of Western propaganda and a weakness in the faith of us Muslims ourself, seen clearly when comparing it to that of those in the said Golden Age of Islam.

@userNameAsString Objective measures of success such as medical advancement, technological advancement, surgery are not "Western propaganda". Its high time we accept the fact that our people are redundant when it comes to providing value to society and stop coping.

@GyroGearloose Agreed.
